# Use a static webpage in Jekyll as the homepage

Tags: jekyll, minima

I have created a website using `Jekyll` with the default theme `minima`. The homepage of this website shows the blog posts.

I would like to show a static page, like `about.md`, as the homepage and move the blog posts to a link such as `website.com/blog/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Minima as your site's theme, what you're looking for can be easily achieved.

Step 1: Add a new folder named `blog` at the root of your website.

Step 2: Create an `index.md` page with the `home` layout, inside this `blog` directory.

```
---
# This file is at `./blog/index.md`

layout: home
title: Morteza's Blog
---
```

Step 3: Change your original `./index.md` file to use the `page` layout.

```
---
# This file is at `./index.md`

layout: page
title: Landing Page
---
```

**NOTE:** If you don't want to maintain a `blog` directory just to house a single `index.md` file, you can create a file called `blog.md` and set it use the `home` layout and render into `blog/index.html`

```
---
# This file is at `./blog.md`

layout: home
title: Morteza's Blog
permalink: /blog/
---
```